# Marshmallow FINE and COARSE location permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to access `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and if it cannot be found access `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`. So I request for those 2 permission, but they give me the same dialog asking for location permission. I know those are both in the same group but Google says:

> **Note:** Your app still needs to explicitly request every permission it needs, even if the user has already granted another permission in the same group. In addition, the grouping of permissions into groups may change in future Android releases. Your code should not rely on the assumption that particular permissions are or are not in the same group.

This means I ask for those 2 permissions within a second, which results in 2 dialog in a row. THis does not seem very user friendly to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: I am currently asking myself the same. Doesn't `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` contain the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in itself? E.g., if you can have a fine location, you should be able to get approximate location maybe?

Comment: are u using Network provider for getting location or only using GPS?

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You do not need `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission when you define `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.

**From Android Documentation:**

> **Requesting User Permissions**
>
> In order to receive location updates from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` or
>   `GPS_PROVIDER`, you must request user permission by declaring either the
>   `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission,
>   respectively, in your Android manifest file. For example:
>
> ```
> <manifest>
>       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
>        .......
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> Without these permissions, your application will fail at runtime when
>   requesting location updates.
>
> **Note:** If you are using both `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER`, then
>   you need to request only the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, because
>   it includes permission for both providers. (Permission for
>   `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` includes permission only for `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.)

Please look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score -2):

I have resolved the same problem.Try to give it runtime permission and Firstly check the manifest SDK version and if your version is greater than 6.0 or equal to 6.0 then you need to check permissions for your permission and pass permission Fine location only in request location then definitely it will work.

if you got stuck in code then you may ask for code I will update you but firstly go through these steps. 
if you got success to perform your task then rate it.